# WPF / PowerShell ListBox : Change foreground color of item if it matches *expression*

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell

I am trying to change the foreground color of items in ListBox depending on their content.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox_advList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="277" Margin="10,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="491">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="GIE">
                        <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="Console Admin Tools">
                        <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="Orange" />
                    </Trigger>                               
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

I would like to change the color of each item to green or orange, if they **match** 'success' or 'failure'.

In other words, is there some kind of -match or -like applying to triggers that I could use, so that I can change the color of the item if it *contains* 'success' or 'failure' ?

I found this article :
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/883626/Wpf-Trigger-If-contains-value
But I don't know how to convert that code to WPF / XAML.

Thanks a lot guys,

Tristan

**EDIT**
Here is the rest of the code, if it helps :

```
$WPF_button_getAdv.add_Click({

# Clear listBox
$WPF_listBox_advList.Items.Clear()
# Test connection
if (Test-Connection $($WPF_textBox_compName.Text) -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
    # Get ADV
    $advertisement = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM CCM_Softwaredistribution" -Namespace "root\CCM\Policy\Machine\ActualConfig" -Computer $($WPF_textBox_compName.Text) -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate
    # Sort ADV : Group by ADVID -> Foreach Object in the Group, select LAST element
    $global:sortAdv = $advertisement | Group-Object ADV_AdvertisementID | ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Last 1 }
    # Get Status
    $advStatus = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SMS\Mobile Client\Software Distribution\Execution History" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty -Path  $_.PsPath }
    foreach ($item in $global:sortAdv)
        {
        foreach ($value in $advStatus)
            {
            if ($value.PSPath -match $item.PKG_PackageID)
                {
                [array]$listBoxInput += "$($value._State)" + " - $($item.PKG_PackageID)" + " - $($item.PKG_Name)"
                }
            }
        }

    [array]$listBoxInput | ForEach-Object {
    $WPF_listBox_advList.AddText($_)
    }

    }
else { $WPF_textBox_compName.Text = 'Ping KO' }

})
```

What I want to do is change the color of each item depending on the value of *$value._State*. If it contains SUCCESS, item in the listBox should be green, if it contains FAILURE it should be orange / red... Thanks ! :)

Comment: Are you converting this XML to PowerShell objects via a XmlNodeReader/XamlReader? (such as what is explained [here](https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/16/part-ii-deploying-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio/))

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the styles after it is loaded into PowerShell. You only have to find the ListBox control, and then loop through the Items, and format them accordingly. Assuming your parent to this control is assigned to the variable `$Form` you could do:

```
$ListBox = $Form.FindName('listBox_advList')
Switch($ListBox.Items){
    {$_.Content -match 'success'} {$_.Background = 'Green'}
    {$_.Content -match 'failure'} {$_.Background = 'Orange'}
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the switch statement, as you can easily add more conditions to it. As a bonus you can run a `Foreach($item in $collection)` loop then call the switch statement.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but I don't get how I should fill my listBox based on that example. Right now I'm using a ForEach-Object like this : $sortAdv | ForEach-Object { $listBox_advList.AddText($_.PKG_Name) } to add content to the listBox.

Comment: Moreover, the *Background* property can only be set to the whole listBox, not on a per-item basis : there is no $listBox.items.Content and no $listBox.items.Background. Maybe I don't get you right, I'm new at this.

Comment: Any hints ? That's annoying... :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comments until today. `$listbox.items` is a collection of `ListBoxItem` objects. Each of those *does* have both a `Background` and a `Content` property, which you can see in the code that you ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I personally wouldn't go to Triggers to handle this kind of behavior. I would take advantage of the IValueConverter in this case. Using this, we can grab a binding value, send it to a converter, and return a brush color to use.

Example, I want to convert string values that equal "SUCCESS" to return a green brush, and anything else, to return a red brush. This is what I would do:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<!-- Declare my converter as a resource in my window -->
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringToBrushConverter x:Key="colorConverter"></local:StringToBrushConverter>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- My window Content -->
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <!-- String items for listbox (This could be a binded collection of strings) -->
        <ListBox.Items>
            <sys:String>SUCCESS</sys:String>
            <sys:String>SUCCESS</sys:String>
            <sys:String>FAILURE</sys:String>
            <sys:String>SUCCESS</sys:String>
            <sys:String>FAILURE</sys:String>
        </ListBox.Items>

        <!-- Set the item template of the items, to a text block -->
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Bind 'Text' to the string value, bind the foreground to the returned converter value given the string -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Then of course all we would need now is our converter class:

```
public class StringToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((string)value == "SUCCESS") //Return green brush (P.S. Case sensitive)
        {
            return Brushes.Green;
        }
        else if ((string)value == "FOOBAR") //If you ever wanted other color options
        {
            return Brushes.Yellow;
        }

        //Anything not caught will be red. AKA "FAILURE" would belong here.
        return Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I think this is a good method, far easier than using trigger in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this method, as suggested on technet :
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05144c37-4991-46fa-b2d8-dcb0a7f266df/wpf-powershell-listbox-change-foreground-color-of-item-if-it-matches-expression?forum=winserverpowershell

<...>

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework
[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Progress..." WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    Width = "400" Height = "165" ShowInTaskbar = "True">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" Height = "150" Width = "365" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin = "10,35,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$ListBox = $Window.FindName("ListBox")

$itm = new-object System.Windows.Controls.ListboxItem
$itm.Content = 'test red'
$itm.Foreground = 'red'
$ListBox.Items.Add($itm)

$itm = new-object System.Windows.Controls.ListboxItem
$itm.Content = 'test green'
$itm.Foreground = 'green'
$ListBox.Items.Add($itm)

$itm = new-object System.Windows.Controls.ListboxItem
$itm.Content = 'test blue'
$itm.Foreground = 'blue'
$ListBox.Items.Add($itm)

$Window.ShowDialog()
```

Works great, thanks again guys !