# How to change the background color of a specific WPF listbox item via Powershell code?

Tags: wpf, windows-10, powershell-3.0, listboxitem

I have built a WPF form and the form and its controls are all working great.
I can add items via a button-click event, clear the items via a different button-click event, copy the contents of individual listbox items to the clipboard via a double-click event on the listbox.

I just wanted to titivate and change the background color of a specific listbox item via code (not via selected item).
The control variable is $lbxCopy and is working successfully, as in:

```
$lbxCopy.add_MouseDoubleClick($zlbxCopyMouseDoubleClick)
```

The code I am trying to use to change the first item in the listbox is:

```
$lbxCopy.Items[0].Background = "Red"
```

The failure message is:

The property 'Background' cannot be found on this object.
Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At winCopyList_Event_Master.ps1:108 char:1
+ $lbxCopy.Items[0].Background = "Red"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Here is the code from the Window_Loaded event:

```
$zwinCopyListLoaded = {
#- Initial Load of the Listbox data -----
#- Calls a sub-process that successfully load the listbox -----
. $zLoadListBox

$lbxCopy.Background = "Red" 
#- The above works but sets the whole listbox background color.

$lbxCopy.Items[0].Background = "Blue"
#- The above fails !

}#-End of Window Loaded event -----
#-------------------------------------------------------------
#- Window Loaded ~ Event-Monitor -----
$winCopyList.add_Loaded($zwinCopyListLoaded)
```

I want to be able to choose the specific listbox item via a code event, not via a selection event.
I am sure I am doing something stupid, like I have a blindspot, and I am going to smack my head when I get an answer on this titillation that I am floundering over!

Other Notes: Windows 10 desktop; 64 bit architecture; Powershell 4; I don't understand 'C'; I am just a learner with Powershell & WPF; I have searched with Google/MSDN/StackOverflow without success.

I did try and follow this article without success:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8134/Coloring-items-in-a-ListBox

Apologies in advance for my stupidity.

Comment: Try with `Brushes.Red`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that later.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the suggestion in the post below worked successfully, and I am now using it. Many thanks to those who posted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565540#43565540

```
$ListBox = $Window.FindName("ListBox")
#- Repeat the code below for each 'Items.Add' -----
$itm = new-object System.Windows.Controls.ListboxItem
$itm.Content = 'test red'
$itm.Background = 'red'
$ListBox.Items.Add($itm)
```